# Bold and sans serif at once with fontspec and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec

As you know, the code like `\sffamily{\bfseries{...}}` gives bold and serif font at once. If to use `fontspec` (`luatexja-fontspec` in my case) it is not enough just to define bold and sans serif fonts. If try `\sffamily{\bfseries{...}}`, you'll get the next message.

[image]

How to define bold sans serif font?

The MWE is ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}

\setmainjfont[BoldFont=HGMinchoB]{MS Mincho}
\setsansjfont{MS Gothic}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase]{TeX Gyre Heros}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item \textbf{\textsf{試験}}
  \item \textbf{\textsf{Test}}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does MS Gothic have such a font? Please check that at first! Sounds like it hasn't. And please minimize your code to one word. Does a standard documentclass like `article` produce the same error? There are lots of things which distract from the actual problem here.

Comment: `\textsf{}` gives sans serif, not serif.

Comment: LaRiFaRi, 1) How I can check it? 2) OK, the MWE has beed updated 3) Yes, same error it `article` (updated MWE is article)

Comment: @GurebuBokofu Thanks. But still too many fonts loaded here in order to show what you want. I do not know what sans serif kanji would look like. Kick everything out! Or do you have problems with MS Mincho as well? Regarding your question: You will have to google that information or you take a look in your font files by double clicking on them. As it is not my software, I dare to promote http://www.xiles.net/nexusfont/

Comment: `\sffamily` also gives sans serif, not serif, and it does not take an argument.

Comment: `\bfseries` doesn't take an argument either. Also, is the issue with TeX Gyre Heros or MS Gothic? TG Heros is set as the default sans serif.

Comment: It seems like a bug in `luatexja-fontspec`